# Javascript in onclick event not executed while page is loading in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios

I have a link to a page where some heavy calculation is made. The response may be delayed up to 12 seconds. So I want to tell the user that the calculation is in progress by showing a spinner on the page.

The spinner works on Windows 10 but not on IOS.
I have tested it on iPad and MacBook Pro2015 with macOS High Sierra.

For the test I have made this page on an Apache server that runs PHP.

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET['wait'])) {
    sleep(12); // set script on server to sleep for 12 sec.
  }
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Test IOS Spinner</title>
 <style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #wait {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: rgba(224, 224, 224, 0.6);
    }

    .loader {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50vh;
        left: 50vw;
        margin: 4px auto;
        border: 4px solid blue;
        border-top: 4px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes spin {
        0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="wait">
      <div class="loader">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="index.php?wait" onclick="testspinner()">Wait 12 secunds</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function testspinner() {
           document.getElementById('wait').style.display = 'block';
       };
    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

- Windows:
  When I run the code above and click on the link then the spinner appears 
  while the page is loading.
  I have tested it in Chrome 63, IE 11 and Firefox 58.
- IOS:
  When I click on the link the spinner does not appear while the page is 
  loading.
  If I stop the page loading within the 12 seconds, the spinner appears. 
  I have tested it in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

It seems browsers on IOS does not continue the javascript while you have made a request to the server.

what am I doing wrong. Is there a workaround?

/Jesper

Comment: Try this if you can use jquery:  $(document).on('click','a', function(){
           document.getElementById('wait').style.display = 'block';
       }) and remove onclick in your html

Comment: @NightRyder: It gives the same result, unfortunately.

Comment: Use setTimeout as @Oscar paz said in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try putting the spinner *before* making the server request:

```
<a href="index.php?wait" onclick="testspinner(event)">Wait 12 secunds</a>
```

Now, in `testspinner`:

```
function testspinner(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('wait').style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(function() {
        // let the browser render, and navigate:
        window.location = 'index.php?wait';
    }, 0);
}
```

I used a call to `setTimeout` so the browser has time to render the spinner before making the request, though I'm not sure that is necessary. I can test it right now. It might work just doing `window.location = ...` directly.

Comment: That is of course a valid solution I also have in my mind. However, I cannot figure out why browsers on IOS are blocking the script while the page is loading.

Comment: About that, no idea. I just hate Safari on iOS, 99% of the problems I got in mobile web apps always happen on iOS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyway :-) I will try to do this instead.

Comment: I have tested the solution on my iPad. The spinner does appear but it does not spin. So it seems that IOS also block the animation. Hmm. So there might not be a workaround for this one.

Comment: No. It seems that safari completely stops the UI from working. Maybe to save battery, who knows ...